# I want to connect the same item in both of mongo dB mongoose list array

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose-schema

I have a user have user schema and order schema how I can make same updates on both so I can update status of them when it be inside the user orders list array and in orders list (I mean to be in both places but same object) **[note : sorry about spaces in code I'm new in stack Overflow ([1][in photo I just added the way I used but its only update in orders is there a way please help] )**

```
//user Schema
  User = mongoose model("User", {
  id: String,
  FirstName: String,
  Last name: String,
  Email: String,
  Password: String,
  cur Password: String,
  rank: String,
  cart List: Array,
  wish List: Array,
  **orders List: Array,**
});
//order Schema
**order = mongoose model("order", {
  user Id: String,
  order Id: String,
  list Items: Array,
  date Place Order : Date,
  date Arrived Order :Date,
  status : String,
  closed : Boolean
});**
```

Comment: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pRZn0.png

Answer (score 0):

i just used a other method by reference connect order in schema

[{type:mongoose.Schema.Types:ObjectId, ref: 'order'}]